# How to Convert Unicode To List?

Tags: python

Can someoene help me to convert unicode to list 
my unicode data looks like this

```
data=[u'1APT', u'CCS', u'COMRM']

data =type 'unicode'
```

And want to convert it to

```
data=['1APT', 'CCS','COMRM']

data = type 'list'
```

here are more details for my problem, here is code

```
genlist2= request.POST['data2']
print type(genlist2)
print "genlist2"
print genlist2
for d in genlist2:
    print d
```

Output:

```
type 'unicode'

[u'1APT', u'CCS', u'COMRM']

[

u

'

1

A

p

T

etc..
```

Why in output in for loop , I get every character separated , i want

```
1APT
CCS
COMRM
??
```

Comment: You already have a list, a list of unicode strings..

Comment: This syntax is invalid, so it's not clear what form your data actually takes. It looks like it's already a list. Could you use actual Python syntax, so we know what we're dealing with?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> data = map(str, data)
>>> data
['1APT', 'CCS', 'COMRM']
```

But you may want to question your need for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>newdata = [i.encode() for i in data]
>>>print newdata
['1APT', 'CCS', 'COMRM']
```

EDIT:

I have understood what's your problem. `genlist2` is a string, and its content is just like a python list.

```
genlist2 = "[u'1APT', u'CCS', u'COMRM']"
```

`eval(genlist2)` will return a list which is what you want.
`eval()` is usually not safe and have some other problems, you can reference [Is using eval in Python a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice/1832957#1832957) .

I don't know other ways to get what you want.

Comment: this won't work for me , when I do it I get ['[', 'u', "'", '1', 'A', 'P', 'T', "'", ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'C', 'C', 'S

Comment: I want as your print out ['1APT', 'CCS', 'COMRM']

Comment: I will explain my problem in more detaisl , I have data structure [u'1APT', u'CCS', u'COMRM'] , that stores with  vobs = request.POST['data2']

Comment: when I run  for data in vobs:  print data

Comment: every character in each itereations are stored in data

Comment: I want in each iteration   stored in data 1APT   then CCS and etc.

Comment: when I received same variable with vobs  request.session['vobs'] , it is type : list and all works normally

Comment: when I print    request.session['vobs']    and   request.POST['data2']  , I get same result , only different type  request.session['vobs'] is list ,  request.POST['data2']  is unicode

Comment: I checked type with print type(vobs)

Comment: @ivan, I could not quite understand your question described here, could you add the description here in a well-formed format and update the problem above?

Comment: please check now,  I updated my question ... You should now understand my question and maybe help me to resolve this weird situtation